# ScalaFX - How to get the title of a Scene using a method

Tags: scala, user-interface, javafx, scalafx

I am using ScalaFX and trying to learn how it works. As an exerpiment (not what I will do in production) I want a method that gets the title of a window.

So here is my Graph.scala file:

```
package graphing

import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.paint.Color

class Graph {
  val app = new JFXApp {
    stage = new JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
      title = "First GUI"
      scene = new Scene {
        fill = Color.Coral
      }
    }
  }

  def getTitle() = {
    app.stage.getTitle
  }

  def generateChart(args: Array[String]) = app.main(args)
}
```

Here is my driver object that makes use of this Graph class:

```
package graphing

import graphing.Graph

object Driver extends App {
  val graph = new Graph

println(graph.getTitle())

  graph.generateChart(args)
}
```

However, this does not work due to the line

> println(graph.getTitle())

The error that is thrown:
[image]

Could someone kindly explain what is going on and how I can achieve my goal here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here concerns *JavaFX* (and hence, *ScalaFX*) initialization.

Initializing *JavaFX* is a complex business. (Indeed, I only recently learned that it was *even more complicated* than I originally believed it to be. Refer to [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62001855/2593574) here on *StackOverflow* for further background. Fortunately, your problem is a little easier to resolve.)

*ScalaFX* simplifies *JavaFX* initialization greatly, but requires that the `JFXApp` trait be used as part of the definition of an `object`.

`JFXApp` contains a `main` method, which *must* be the starting point of your application; it is this method that takes care of the complexities of initializing *JavaFX* for you.

In your example, you have your `Driver` object extend `scala.App`, and so it is `App`'s  (and hence, `Driver`'s) `main` method that becomes the starting point of your own application. This is fine for a regular *command line interface* (*CLI*) application, but it cannot be used with *ScalaFX*/*JavaFX* applications without a great deal of additional complexity.

In your code, `JFXApp`'s `main` method never executes, because, as it is defined as a class member, it is not the `main` method of a *Scala* `object`, and so is not a candidate for automatic execution by the *JVM*. You do call it manually from your `Graph.generateChart()` method, but that method itself is not called until *after* you try to get the title of the scene, hence the *NPE* as the stage has not yet been initialized.

What if you put the `graph.generateChart(args)` call *before* the `println(graph.getTitle())` statement? Will that fix it? Sadly, no.

Here's why...

`JFXApp` also performs one other bit of *magic*: it executes the construction code for its `object` (and for any other `class`es extended by that object, but not for extended `trait`s) on the *JavaFX Application Thread* (*JAT*). This is important: only code that executes on the *JAT* can interact directly with *JavaFX* (even if through *ScalaFX*). If you attempt to perform *JavaFX* operations on any other thread, including the application's main thread, then you will get exceptions.

(This *magic* relies on a deprecated *Scala* trait, `scala.DelayedInit`, which has been removed from the libraries for *Scala 3.0*, aka *Dotty*, so a different mechanism will be required in the future. However, it's worth reading [the documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/DelayedInit.html) for that trait for further background.)

So, when `Driver`'s construction code calls `graph.generateChart(args)`, it causes *JavaFX* to be initialized, starts the *JAT*, and executes `Graph`'s construction code upon it. However, by the time `Driver`'s constructor calls `println(graph.getTitle())`, which is still executing on the main thread, there are two problems:

1. `Graph`'s construction code may, or may not, have been executed, as it is being executed on a different thread. (This problem is called a *race condition*, because there's a race between the main thread trying to call `println(graph.getTitle())`, and the *JAT* trying to initialize the `graph` instance.) You may win the race on some occasions, but you're going to lose quite often, too.
2. You're trying to interact with *JavaFX* from the main thread, instead of from the *JAT*.

Here is the recommended approach for your application to work:

```scala
package graphing

import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.paint.Color

object GraphDriver
extends JFXApp {

  // This executes at program startup, automatically, on the JAT.
  stage = new JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
    title = "First GUI"
    scene = new Scene {
      fill = Color.Coral
    }
  }

  // Print the title. Works, because we're executing on the JAT. If we're NOT on the JAT,
  // Then getTitle() would need to be called via scalafx.application.Platform.runLater().
  println(getTitle())

  // Retrieve the title of the stage. Should equal "First GUI".
  //
  // It's guaranteed that "stage" will be initialized and valid when called.
  def getTitle() = stage.title.value
}
```

Note that I've combined your `Graph` class and `Driver` object into a single object, `GraphDriver`. While I'm not sure what your application needs to look like architecturally, this should be an OK starting point for you.

Note also that `scala.App` is not used at all.

Take care when calling `GraphDriver.getTitle()`: this code needs to execute on the *JAT*. The standard workaround for executing any code, that might be running on a different thread, is to pass it *by name* to `scalafx.application.Platform.runLater()`. For example:

```scala
import scalafx.application.Platform

// ...
Platform.runLater(println(ObjectDriver.getTitle()))
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you for this - this was incredibly insightful!

Comment: Hi just following up on this - suppose I wanted to build a visualization package based on ScalaFX. I want to use this package to do:

import myPackage
run some code generating data
myPackage.plot(data)

i.e the running of my package happens inside any class I choose, not just one that extends JFXApp.

To me it seems that since JFXApp is always the starting point, I cannot do this. Am I correct?

Comment: @finite_diffidence Not knowing exactly what you're trying to do, I can't help too much. Maybe you should ask another question with the necessary details? However, I don't see any reason why you shouldn't be able to use _ScalaFX_, or that starting from `JFXApp` prevents you from doing what you need.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will post a new question. I would really like to use ScalaFX, but I am just a bit of a noob haha